# Unable to filter dataframe list

Tags: pandas

I have a list of dataframes that I'd like to filter out some rows.

```
d = {'id': ['111', '222', '333'], 'queries': ['High', 'Mid', 'Low'], 'time_stay': ['High', 'Mid', 'Low']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'id': ['444', '555'], 'queries': ['True', 'False'], 'time_stay': ['High', 'Mid']}
dd2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df_list = [dd, dd2]
```

df_list

```
[    id queries time_stay
 0  111    High      High
 1  222     Mid       Mid
 2  333     Low       Low,
     id queries time_stay
 0  444    True      High
 1  555   False       Mid]
```

If the dataframe length == 3, I'd like to only keep the row where `queries` == `Low`

```
for df in df_list:
    if len(df) == 3:
        df = df.loc[df['queries'] == 'Low']
    else:
        pass
```

The code `df.loc[df['queries'] == 'Low']` works as expected but when I check `df_list[0]`, the result is not saved.

The expected output should be:

df_list[0]

```
333 Low Low
```

I also would like to rewrite it into a list comprehensive format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a lambda function:

```
df_list = list(map(lambda df: df[df.queries == 'Low'] if len(df) == 3 else df, df_list))
```

**Output**

```
df_list
[    id queries time_stay
 2  333     Low       Low,
     id queries time_stay
 0  444    True      High
 1  555   False       Mid]
```